# Unwanted space at the bottom of View after UILabel using ScrollView

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, uilabel

[image]I have got a view which I have attached as screen shot, I have got unwanted space at the bottom of the second UILabel, the content coming into that UILabel is from a web url JSON using Alamofire. I have set the lines to 0. I can understand why the space is there because its a label and does not fill the height of the bottom, but if I change the height to fit it, the texts gets truncated. So how do i avoid this extra space. I have added all relevant constraints. I am fairly new to Swift.

[image]

Comment: Do you have a `UIImageView` and 2 `UILabel` inside a `UIScrollView`? What should be the minimum height of the `UIImageView`? If possible can you please add what constraints you have tried?

Comment: What are your settings for padding and margins on the UILabel?

Comment: I have added image of the constraints, but the height is dynamic depending on the JSON content feed

Comment: Can you describe what layout you want to implement? How do you imagine no space at the bottom if those labels contain only one line of text each?

Comment: @alexburtnik. I have set the lines to 0, so that the text would adapt to the content feed, like I said I am fairly new to swift, so If you know a better way let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it, I stretched the bottom labels height to fill the bottom and took off the height constraint. Also in the ViewController I added

```
    articleContentValue.sizeToFit()
```